# Who owns Superman?

Tags: halacha, business, legal-documents

In the 1930s, two Jewish boys, Jerry Siegel and Joe Shuster, created the comic book character *Superman*. In 1938, badly in need of money, they sold the rights to the character for $130, to what would later become DC Comics. *Superman* was a huge success and generated millions in profit, but his creators got nothing.  They sued, but after [decades of litigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_lawsuits_by_Superman%27s_creators#2010%E2%80%932013:_DC_sues_the_Shuster_heirs) they lost: The contract they signed was found to be valid.  They lived near poverty all their lives.

If they had gone to a bet din, how would halacha view the matter?

(Possible considerations: Is this type of contract valid?  Is a contract valid when signed under duress (taking advantage of people in need to buy their stuff for a pittance)? Is intellectual property covered in halacha?  There are "finders keepers" rules in Bava Metzia, but can we say the "find" here is the success of *Superman*?  Does DC Comics have an ethical, if not a contractual, obligation?)

Comment: Why do you suspect the result would be any different?

Comment: Was $130 a fair price at the time? If so, then what's their claim here?

Comment: Not a rabbi or a lawyer, but they did sell the rights for $130. Maybe not very much, but they did do it. So DC Comics rightfully owned Superman. I just think the two creators got the short end of the stick because they didn't realize how popular the character would be, but that's 100% their fault.

Comment: @DoubleAA how is this a duplicate? That's about patents and this is about trademarks and copyright.

Comment: @msh210 I see that distinction as less problematic than the fact that this one has a details begging questions of unfair business and contracts.

Comment: The mentioned article says nothing about a contractual sale, much less one done under duress.

Comment: Would the events described in [Genesis 25:29-34](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.25.29-34) be enough to settle your question ?

Comment: @Lucian -- If Esau's sale of his birthright was binding and final, why did Jacob have to resort to trickery to get Isaac's blessing?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi: A birthright presupposes a birther and a birthed, and Jacob tricked them both.